# Phrasal verb of go that means break?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What is the phrasal verb of the word **go** that means ***break***? I've thought of **go beyond** but it seems to be unsuitable. So what is the correct phrasal verb?

Comment: Can you add an example sentence please?

Comment: @MaxWilliams the phrasal verb that can mean the word **break** in **break his promises"

Comment: Possibly "go wrong"?

Comment: That's not a sentence...

Comment: @MaxWilliams I don't have the full sentences, sorry

Answer (score 3):

**"to go back on"** means to fail to honor or keep (one's word/promise)

> - [**go back on something**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-back-on)
>
>   to fail to do something that you have promised or agreed to do.
>
>   go back on your word/promise: "Both leaders feared that the other would go back on his word."

Examples from the web:

- "He wouldn't go back on his word."
- "The government looks likely to go back on its decision to close the mines."
- "She's gone back on her word and decided not to give me the job after all."
- "Many people think it's rude to go back on a promise."
- "James went back on his promise to get a new car for his wife."